# My submit update button requires a hidden type to work, can't figure out why

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make my update button, not require the following to be functional:

```
<input type="hidden" name="function" value="update_issue" />
```

Here is my Working Code at the moment:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update"  />                                            
<input type="hidden" name="function" value="update_issue" />                       
<input type="hidden" name="iOwner" value="<?php print $row['ticketManager']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="iid" value="<?php print $row['id_pit_tickets']; ?>" />  

if(isset($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == "update_issue"){
//code...
}
```

Not Working Code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="function" />                      
<input type="hidden" name="iOwner" value="<?php print $row['ticketManager']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="iid" value="<?php print $row['id_pit_tickets']; ?>" />

if(isset($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == "Update"){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given your submit button a `name`. Fields with no name are **NOT** submitted:

```
<input type="submit" name="function" value="Update" />
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can verify that the form is being submitted properly by doing a `var_dump($_POST)` in PHP. That'll show you exactly what PHP parsed out of whatever the client submitted. If your field isn't there, then something on the client is preventing it from going out: html errors, javascript processing, etc...

Comment: My submit button has the name function, but still doesn't seem to post correctly.

Comment: Then try the var_dump() and see what's coming through.

Comment: Figured it out, naming was wrong. Thanks Marc.